# Is there a term for letting out an exasperated sigh through the nose?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for when a person is getting really irritated/frustrated by someone, but they don't want to yell, so they do that thing where they exhale sharply through their nose?

Say, for example, in customer support the operator has to explain and re-explain a procedure over and over, but the caller can never seem to get it right.

To be clear, I'm talking about the act of blowing air out of the nose when angry/frustrated as opposed to breathing an exasperated sigh out of the mouth. It's just air; there's no vocalization or loud sound like a snort.

Comment: @interploy: For most contexts it's *inhalation = **sniff**, exhalation = **snort***. But actually a "disdainful sniff" is far more likely to involve exhalation. Compare [tutting](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tut), which in my experience nearly always involves air being taken *into* the mouth, rather than being forced out.

Comment: ...I think the word for your context would probably be ***sigh*** - it's just a "slightly supressed" sigh, where the mouth is kept closed.

Comment: It's snort whether you breathe in or out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize my definition of snort was so far off. I guess "sighing through their nose" is the correct phrase.

Comment: There's an obsolete _snuffle_ meaning 'to show dislike or disdain by snuffing; to sniff at a thing in contempt' which still gets a little run out every now and then in Aus/NZ in _snufflebuster_. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snufflebuster

Comment: To clarify, the sound made by breathing out through the nose while obstructing that sound in kind of a rough nasal aspiration is commonly what we mean when we say *snort*.

Comment: @interpoloy: No, "sighing through the nose" is not the correct phrase. It is a decidedly inferior phrase that will only serve to confuse people, no matter what Fumblefingers tells you.

Comment: @Robusto: That's typically what I think of when I hear the term snort. Either like a boar snorting before a charge, or a person trying to inhale with a stuffed nose with that *hrrrnk* sound. The action I'm thinking of doesn't have a sound with it, only air through the nostrils. If "sigh through their nose" isn't right, then maybe Frank's term 'snuffle' would be closest (though snuffle refers more to sadness or sickness and not anger).

Comment: @Robusto: I'm not telling OP to use *sigh through the nose*. I'm just saying that if I understand the context correctly, most native speakers would use ***sigh*** (perhaps adapted as *He let out a suppressed sigh*). I'd say that in general *snorting* is "aggressive" - as opposed to *sighing*, which is "frustrated/resigned".

Comment: http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Suppressed sigh" sounds just about right. An "exasperated sigh" would be right if the person was using their mouth, so would "suppressed an exasperated sigh" convey the image of exhaling through the nose in an annoyed way?

Comment: @John Lawler: That's really helpful to the overall dialog I'm writing (so thanks!), but none of the terms quite match what I'm looking for in this case.

Comment: @interploy: I think we're well into the territory of "writing advice" by now. But no - I don't think your version works so well, because *suppressed* implies he *didn't* "let it out" at all. With my suggested ***let out** a suppressed sigh* it's obvious at least *some* "exhalation" took place. Probably through the nose, since you don't want to use your mouth because it's so close to your phone mic, but in most contexts no-one would care much about that level of detail. And the "exasperated" aspect should be obvious in almost any real-world context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's a good point. Sorry, I didn't mean for it to spill into writing advice territory. I was just looking for a succinct term for an awkward phrase. It doesn't look like there is a single-word term for it though, so I'll take "let out a suppressed sigh" as the best, not-awkward phrase.

Comment: If we're looking for *sniff/snort-type words*, I'm familiar with ***snack** = to exchange sharp words*, which is close to OP's context (assuming the "caller" can hear the dismissive/aggressive "sigh"). Also you can ***snaffle*** a horse, so it can't open its mouth, and must perforce breathe (angrily) through its nose.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think "let out a suppressed sigh" is still the best option based on the context. The person is trying to avoid saying sharp words and snaffle seems to refer to the bit itself so it may not apply when there is no bridle involved. I'll confirm your suppressed sigh comments if you want to put them as the answer.

Comment: @interploy: To "let out a suppressed sigh" will not be perceived to involve the nose.

Comment: @Robusto: It's still the closest to what I'm looking for. A sigh is through the mouth. A snort implies a sound other than just air. A snuffle is quiet, but it's meant for when a person is sick or sad, not angry. The archaic version of snuffle is technically correct, but it's so far out of use very few will get the meaning I intended. And Lawler's examples are either sounds other than breath or are facial expressions. I think my example is just too specific to have its own term in modern English.

Comment: @Robusto: A suppressed sigh implies exasperation and I can just leave it to the reader if that is done through the nose or mouth.

Comment: OED has 4 headings for ***snaffle***. The first matches "put a bridle on" as per my earlier comment. The third is: *Now dial. (a. trans.) **To utter through the nose.***

Comment: @interploy: Then perhaps it would be wise to remove the reference to *nose* from the title.

Comment: @Robusto: I edited the title and description to try to be clearer on what I'm asking. Hope that helps.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think you are correct that OP is describing a type of sigh. Personally, I "sigh" in frustration in both ways, though I'm not conscious of why I choose one or the other. Whereas, a "snort" is an expression of derision or contempt.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Snorting cocaine is inhalation, not exhalation. [Reference](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snort), notice that  1.2 and 1.3 (noun) and 1.2 (verb) all refer to an _inward_ motion (even though 1.3 is figurative, it's still clearly inward)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Huff" would be the word that I have seen used for this.  It was difficult to come up with a list of citations - The surnames Huff and Huffington cluttered up the results.
A. A. Milne apparently believes that snails "huffle" when they are in danger.  That's a small joke - see his poem "Four Friends".

Comment: OED: ***huffle** n. a sudden gust of wind, or **the sound made by this.*** The actual *sound* of a sudden gust would presumably be as insignificant as [James the huffling snail](http://allpoetry.com/The-Four-Friends).

Comment: This actually might be the word I'm looking for. When you say "huff" or "huffed", is that a state of being angry or an action you do when angry?

Comment: When you huff you make a small burst of air out through your nose.  If someone says you are "huffing and puffing" they mean that you are exerting yourself and breathing in and out very forcefully.  If you huff because you are slightly angry and or disgusted, you close your mouth and make a very slight puff out through your nose.  Some one on the other end of a phone conversion might or might not hear you.  You can also "walk off in a huff" because you've been pushed too far.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I mean then, thanks! I'm glad there was a term for it after all.

Comment: @interploy Glad to help. English is a very expressive language.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps *[humph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humph)*

> \a snort articulated as a syllabic m or n with a voiceless onset and ending in a nasal h or a glottal stop; often read as ˈhəm(p)f\
>   Definition of HUMPH
>
> —used to express doubt or contempt

This nasal interjection is distinct from the throaty interjection, *[harrumph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harrumph)*

> - to clear the throat in a pompous way
> - to comment disapprovingly

which can be verbal or on-verbal.

both *Merriam-Webster*

Comment: this is really close. Is there a noiseless version of "humph"? I guess not entirely noiseless, but air only, no vocalization?

Comment: I think *snort* is probably the closest of you wan't to sounds but air.

Comment: Snort implies a much louder sound than what I'm thinking of. This is more the level of a sigh.

Answer (score 1):

Although [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scoff) do not explicitly support it, writers of closed captioning for film and TV seem consistently to have settled on the verb *scoff* to indicate this specific manner of expressing contempt or irritation. (The word more generally signifies expressing derision by whatever means.) *Flaring one’s nostrils* is an associated physical sign, though of course that can be done without any such sharp exhalation as is here inquired about.

Comment: The meaning is good, but I usually see "scoff" in relation to some kind of vocalization, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Suspirates would be the closest description, but not commonly used.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site which seeks to provide *definitive* answers. As such, your answer would be greatly strengthened with an explanation— *why* would you propose *suspirates*? What is its dictionary definition? What are some examples in literature or journalism? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of sound that comes with the air blowing out of the nose. If you're looking for a word that describes the same kind of soft sound that comes out of the mouth when a person sighs, I would call it the same word--a sigh. A snort makes a completely different sound and is also used to describe inhalation. I can't think of another word that makes the same kind of soft sound, so I would apply "sigh" when it comes out of the either the mouth or the nose.