# A word for air that comes from your nose rather than your mouth?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a concise, non-clumsy way of referring to breath that comes from one's nose rather than from one's mouth.  A single-word would be nice.

I've done a Google search to no avail and reviewed [*Is There a Term for Letting Out an Exasperated Sigh Through the Nose*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226352/is-there-a-term-for-letting-out-an-exasperated-sigh-through-the-nose) but it's not what I'm looking for.  *Huff* and *humph* were some of the good answers there but it wouldn't quite work in the sentence I am thinking of.

"Bad breath can be mitigated by not breathing through your mouth.    **Air that comes from your nose rather than your mouth** is less smelly.

[One word for the all bold words would be beautifully concise if it exists!]

One post suggested *suspirate* which doesn't appear to be a word but that led me to [suspire](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195190) (verb) and [suspiration](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195188) (noun) which are.  Unfortunately, according to a review of the OED entries these mean sigh and don't denote a sigh through the nose.

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable, but preferably something shorter than the phrase I came up with!

Comment: I believe GEdgar's response is the best answer. "Nasal air".  On a different topic, I am new to this site. I wonder why the best answers in this site are usually in comments rather than answers. Is it because of reputation fear?

Comment: What is reputation fear?

Comment: @Syed Danish Anwar It's for a variety of reasons. The question might be considered inappropriate on ELU but an answer helpfully provided in a comment. Or the _answer_ suggested might be considered not really of ELU standard. I've countered the upvote for your answer, sadly, as writing advice is not appropriate on ELU. A one word synonym for 'air that comes from your nose rather than your mouth' is optimal; a short (4 words maximum) string as a synonym might be considered appropriate for the site. But 'air from your nose' doesn't work without prior context, and is not a suitable answer on ELU.

Comment: The single-word thing gets old very fast.

Comment: @thomj1332 By reputation fear, I meant the fear of losing reputation due to downvotes.  Comments cannot be down voted. I've noticed members posting answers to questions in comments even when there is no answer, which seems a bit comical to be frank. I believe the comment section is a type of a loophole to maintain reputation.

Comment: I confess to using comments for answers on occasion when I don't have the time or inclination to document my answers and am certain that even a useful answer will be downvoted by someone who is a stickler for the rules. ELU regulars tend to be more dogmatic on this point than on other SE sites.

Comment: What is the etiquette when someone drops a useful answer in the comments but doesn't want to work up an official answer?  Who should pick up the mantle?

Comment: "nasal exhalations are" is more concise, but artless.  Sometimes using more words is the best way to convey your idea, and I think you do this well in your original.

Comment: I concur with OPs intention to refine the sentence.  The above sentence can be shortened to achieve conciseness, which is one of the Cs of effective communication.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the sentence in the bold concise by removing 'that comes'.

Also, you can remove the words 'rather than your mouth' as the comparison is obvious after reading the first sentence. So, the sentence could be made concise as follows.

Bad breath can be mitigated by not breathing through your mouth. Air from your nose is less smelly.